# How to use global variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using global variables but I can't do it with out any errors. I can't remember how to completely use global variables. If you have any tips please tell me.

My code is below

```
print(" Greenfly Population Model")
    chocies=[]
    def Newgen():
        global GA=Gen0_A #duplicates adults numbers
        global GJ=Gen0_J #duplicates juvenile numbers
        global Gen0_J=(Gen0_A*Birth_rate) #calculates new number of juveniles
        global Gen0_A=(GJ*Srate_J) #calulates new number of adults
        global Gen0_S =((GA*Srate_A)+(Gen0_S*Srate_S)) #calculates new number of seniles
        global Total = Gen0_J+Gen0_A+Gen0_S #calculates total number of greenflies



def option1():
    if chocies==[]:
        print("Set the Generation 0 values!")
    else:
        print(chocies[:])
def option2():
    print("Display the Generation 0 values")

def option3():
    print("Run the model")

def option4():
    print("Export data")

def option5():
    print("Quit")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("GOOD BYE")
    time.sleep(1)
    # exiting the loop


print("""
1- Set the Generation 0 values
2- Display the Generation 0 values
3- Run the model
4- Export Data
5- Quit
""")#all different options


s = int(input("from the menu above please pick your choice"))
print("setting the generation 0 values")
i = int(input("Enter the number of generations you want the model to run for"))

G0_A = int(input("Choose adult survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
GJ = int(input("Choose Juvenile survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
G0_S  = int(input("Choose Senile survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
r = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of juvenile:"))
a = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of adults:"))
i = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of seniles:"))
v = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of the adults:"))

print(s)
print(i)
print(m)
print(o)
print(n)
print(r)
print(a)
print(i)
print(v)

print("Greenfly Population Model")
print("""
1- Set the Generation 0 values
2- Display the Generation 0 values
3- Run the model
4- Export Data
5- Quit
""")#all different options

l = int(input("Please select an option from the menu above:"))
print("Displaying the generation 0 values")
e = int(input("The number of new generations to model is:"))
n = int(input("The initial population for the adults is:"))
o = int(input("The initial population for the Seniles is:"))
v = int(input("The initial population for the Juveniles is:"))
o = int(input("The Birthrate for the adults is:"))
i = int(input("The Survival rate for the Adults is:"))
t = int(input("The survival rate for the seniles is:"))

print(l)
print(e)
print(n)
print(o)
print(v)
print(o)
print(i)
print(t)

print("Greenfly Population Model")
print("""
1- Set the Generation 0 values
2- Display the Generation 0 values
3- Run the model
4- Export Data
5- Quit
""")#all different options

int(input("please select an option from the menu above:"))

print("Opening the file")
text_file = open("read_it.txt", "r")
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Why are you using global variables here? And so many too

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: I have used global varibles because I thought I needed to please make any changes neccesery

Comment: I'm not getting an error I just need to put the global variables through out the code but I am not sure where

Comment: You fundamentally misunderstand how variable scope and the `global` keyword works. Please read up before asking a question. https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Comment: can you help change the code though?

Comment: @SimonRaivid SO is a Q&A site. You should try and do some research yourself, and pinpoint where you struggle. This code is long, I doubt someone would just read it all and figure what it suppose to do. Try it yourself, and ask more specific questions

Comment: I have but I do need help please try and change my code so that my global will work

Comment: I doubt anyone can write code for you if they do not understand the problem you are having. Please refrain from asking for free labour, and instead specify what you are having trouble with, with the understanding that it will always be you that fixes it.

Comment: I get an error on line 4 column 14 with an =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of your globals is wrong. You declare your globals as a description of how they should be calculated. That will just not work. The global keyword in python is used to bring a variable in the local scope. Then you can alter it. Like this:

```
def updateGlobals():
    global global_variable
    global_variable = "new value"
```

However, I would put them your globals in a class and add functions that will update the variables accordingly. I think people call this the singleton design pattern, but maybe you don't need this in your little project.

Comment: This tells honestly nothing. If you want to have help with an error, you should state what the error is, and where the error occured (so what is on line 4).

Comment: the = sign is the issue

Comment: You still haven't shared any code, nor did you tell me what the error was.